# Naming a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I want to name this jQuery function like "showElements". How can I do that?

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($,undefined) {
    $.showElements = function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
        });
        $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
        });
        $("ul, li").disableSelection();
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Use it like so: `$.showElements();`

As just a regular function:

```
var showElements = function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
};
```

Use it like so: `showElements();`  Fragile: you're poluting the global scope

Answer (score 2):

First you have to include the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) library and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showElements()
    {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true
        });
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
        $("ul, li").disableSelection();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to call this function from asp.net with OnClient = "ShowElements()". But It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the JQuery is available and Active ?

Comment: @user1993927 do you mean `OnClientClick` ?

Comment: Yes i can drag elements without calling asp.net but whenever i call the function it fails.

Comment: @user1993927 what is the point of  mixing unobtrusive jQuery code with inline `onAnything` ? WHy not just use jQuery all the way and keep it all unobtrusive?

Comment: I am doing dynamic work flow application with asp.net. I don't want to show this elements for the first load. I need to call it from asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

In this case there's no need for the function to be wrapped in the jQuery global ($). Just create the function like this:

```
function showElements() {
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
});
$("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("ul, li").disableSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var showElements = function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true
        });
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
        $("ul, li").disableSelection();
    };

    $(function(){
        showElements();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to see the elements in the page when the first load. I want to see when i click the button.

Comment: then take out that second part of the code, dont call it on the ready event.